# Does C allow function calls as arguments?

Tags: c

For example,

```
atoi(reverse(itoa(p)))
```

Python allows this, and it's a fun feature, but I'm wondering if C allows it as well.

Comment: Best way to learn is try it out yourself

Comment: why not try it out yourself? :)

Comment: There is no such thing as _function call_ outside the interpreter. Python passes _return value_ from callee as _argument_.

Comment: Yes. Function arguments can be expressions.

Comment: Was going to do that, but kinda thought I'd like to ask real quick before I try and get a mile of compiler errors.

Comment: @myaut: I'm not sure what you mean by that. One could argue that there's no such thing as *anything* outside the interpreter in Python.

Comment: `strrev`(or something else) instead of `reverse`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I'm saying that accessing _function call_ (its frame) will require digging into interpreter internals (i.e. with `inspect` module) thus it is not easily accessible from script code.

Comment: @myaut: I think we're using the term "function call" in two different ways. I'm referring to an *expression* like `itoa(p)`. In source code, such an expression can be part of a larger expression, including as an argument for another function call. As with any argument expression, the value passed is the result of evaluating the argument expression -- in this case, calling the function at run time. Implementation details like stack frames are not, I think, something the OP needs to worry about.

Comment: In short: `itoa(p)` is evaluated, and the *result* of that evaluation is passed as an argument to `reverse`, which is evaluated in turn, and that result is passed to `atoi`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The arguments to a function call can all be arbitrary expressions, including function calls.

Generally speaking, there are very few programming languages which don't support this. The ones that don't are generally considered toy languages, unfit for any serious use. :)

Answer (score 1):

Functions arguments can be any valid expression. `reverse(itoa(p))` is an expression and can be used as a function argument.

#### C11: 3.3

1 **argument**

> **expression** in the comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses in a function call expression, [...]

Note that a function call itself an expression.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "function calls as arguments". C language does not provide any built-in means to support lazy evaluation (if your question is intended to be about that). Your

```
atoi(reverse(itoa(p)))
```

expression is valid in C, but it simply stands for

```
tmp1 = itoa(p);
tmp2 = reverse(tmp1);
result = atoi(tmp2);
```

I.e. it simply means that each "nested" function is called "early" and its result is passed as input parameter to the next function in the nested sequence.

The closet you can get to built-in support for lazy evaluation in C is `?:` operator, which can be used in macros (thus preserving its "lazy" nature).